# Why does $\sum_{p\in P} \sum_{k\in N^+} \frac {1}{k.^{2}} $ yield $\ln(\frac{\pi^2}{6})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, riemann-zeta

The source for this problem is this [3b1b video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PDoT7jtxmw&t=7s). I understand this:

$$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Now he alters the series to include only primes and powers of primes (eg. 4 and 8 are included because they are powers of 2, which is prime) while scaling down the powers of primes by a factor of the exponent, as in:

$$\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2(2)}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\frac{1}{8^2(3)}+\frac{1}{9^2(2)}+...$$

This happens to equate to: $$ \ln\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)$$

I tried to search the proof of this for a while, but could not find anything. I would be delighted to see an elementary explanation to this,

Thanks!

Comment: Is the summation meant to be $$\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}^+}\frac{1}{kp^{2k}}$$?

Comment: I don't understand what the series is. Why is $\frac{1}{8^2(3)}$ included, for example?

Comment: @Mark yes, that is a better way to put it, thanks.

Comment: We can deduce the following result using Dirichlet convolution:
$\log(\zeta(s))=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s\log(n)}$, but I can't quite see a connection to the sum you present. I will mention that the numerator in this expression is the Von Mangoldt function.

Comment: @Elliot G the power of primes are scaled down by the exponent. Since 8 is 2 cubed, 1/3 is multiplied to that term.

Comment: @Elliot G Yes, really sorry. That was a typing mistake.

Comment: @DavidKipper I think the connection is that for $n = p^k$, $\Lambda(n) / \log(n) = \log(p) / k\log(p) = 1/k$, so it seems to be precisely the same sum.

Comment: @Mark Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Euler product factorization of the Riemann zeta function is:

$$ \zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}\right)^{-1} $$

Apply natural logarithm with the Newton-Mercator expansion

$$ \ln\zeta(s)=\sum_p -\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)=\sum_p \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{kp^{ks}}.  $$

This is the special case $s=2$.

Comment: In the first line, you have a product over $p$, but no $p$ appears in the formula. Looks like it should be $\prod_p(1-\frac{1}{p^s})^{-1}$?